# iOS & XCode 4 Build Setting: Install Directory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When developing iOS apps with XCode, there is a build setting called Install Directory.  Does XCode ignore this?  I've changed it to /Applications and the app still gets installed in the sandbox.  I'm using a jailbroken phone and would like my app to get installed in /Applications for system read privileges.  The only other way, it seems, is to use SSH to drop the bundle in /Applications.  Doing that forces me to build+archive, thus I can't use the debugger for console output.

Is there a solution to this problem? (I am a paid dev with a proper certificate, no hacks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is mainly for OSX apps, but I think it may also place the main executable inside that directory inside of the App bundle.  So if you had Test.app, the executable binary file would be in `Test.app/Applications/test`.  At least it did that for me a while back when I was messing around with different settings.  It may have changed.

You can use the xcode 'Behaviors' settings to specify a script to run when a build succeeds, or you can set 'Pre-build' and 'Post-build' actions (can also run a custom script) for each scheme in your project.  You could automate the process of SSH'ing and moving the bundle with a post-build script.

---

Edit:

<strike>I just tested changing this setting and building debug/release/test/etc versions of my project, and nothing changed about the bundle or archive that was build.  Seems this setting has no effect on iOS apps.</strike>

Actually, after more testing it does change the directory inside a release archive.  This is how the archive looks after changing that setting to *ApplicationsTest*:

```
[ 12:12 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-09-28 ]$ cd Universal\ 9-28-11\ 12.11\ PM.xcarchive/Products/
[ 12:12 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-09-28/Universal 9-28-11 12.11 PM.xcarchive/Products ]$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 Jonathan  staff   102B Sep 28 12:11 ApplicationsTest
[ 12:12 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-09-28/Universal 9-28-11 12.11 PM.xcarchive/Products ]$ ll ApplicationsTest/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  187 Jonathan  staff   6.2K Sep 28 12:11 Universal.app
```

And changing it to *SomethingElse*:

```
[ 12:15 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-09-28/Universal 9-28-11 12.15 PM.xcarchive/Products ]$ pwd
/Users/Jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-09-28/Universal 9-28-11 12.15 PM.xcarchive/Products
[ 12:15 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-09-28/Universal 9-28-11 12.15 PM.xcarchive/Products ]$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 Jonathan  staff   102B Sep 28 12:14 SomethingElse
[ 12:15 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-09-28/Universal 9-28-11 12.15 PM.xcarchive/Products ]$ ll SomethingElse/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  187 Jonathan  staff   6.2K Sep 28 12:15 Universal.app
```

Comment: Great.  Is there a way you could append a script to your answer that would do what you said, and SSH+drop the bundle into /Applications and launch, including the debugger?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a jail-broken iPhone, so I would have no way to test such a script or else I probably would write it for ya =) (I'm that into python).  But, I can dig up some info on how to ssh in python if that would help ya get started?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python and only know rudimentary terminal commands.  I'm not sure if it would work or not.  I would love to find out, though, so if you have time...  I upvoted your answer and will check mark it if no one else replies in the next day or two

Comment: Actually, you would just need to scp it I think.  Try something like this as a post-biuld script action:  `scp ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME} root@192.168.1.25:/Applications/`.   But replace `192.168.1.25` with the IP/hostname of your iphone and replace `root` with the proper user.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not currently on my WiFi network with my devices so I can't test until I get home, unless there is a variable to set that can move the files along the USB cable. Will the app automatically launch at the end with gdb attached?

Comment: The only way I know of to run the app in gdb after the scp would be to launch the App manually, then attach to the process by the PID or process name via xcode.

Comment: One has to wonder why the Xcode developers make it so hard to get to this directory. In Xcode 3.x and earlier it was easy--do they hate us developers?